How to clear cache for each iteration in postman?
I am validating an API in postman Tool, when I am executing it, for the first time Response time is coming around ~1000 ms and for the remaining iterations response time are around ~200 to 300 ms.
Seems like it is serving the response from cache, how to delete cache for each iteration in postman? I tried the below options but still the Response time pattern remains the same.
By enabling “Headers – Send no-cache header checkbox” option.
By adding headers in the request, “Cache-Control: no-cache & Cache-Control: no-store
